# Parameter tab not loading in SSDT 2015

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to create a package in SSDT 2015. When I click the parameter tab, getting the following error

[image]

Comment: Did you try rebooting/reloading?

Comment: Yes. I have shut visual studio and opened again couple of times.